# How to add dynamically text and tags inside textFlow

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript

```
<s:RichEditableText editable="false" styleName="chatWin" height="550" width="100%">
        <s:textFlow>
            <s:TextFlow>
                    <s:p>Inline<s:br />TextFlow</s:p>
            </s:TextFlow>
        </s:textFlow>
</s:RichEditableText>
```

I want to add this `<s:p>` tag dynamically, thus making a chat...i've tried this:

```
var p:p = new p();
```

but this don't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a declarative text flow within MXML, you could programmatically update the text by appending to a string variable and reflowing with [`TextConverter.importToFlow()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flashx/textLayout/conversion/TextConverter.html#importToFlow%28%29).

Example:

> [image: chat-window]

On enter, text from the input field is appended and reflowed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
               minWidth="955"
               minHeight="600">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import flashx.textLayout.conversion.TextConverter;
            import flashx.textLayout.elements.TextFlow;

            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            [Bindable]
            public var text:String = "<p>Inline<br />TextFlow</p>";

            protected function input_enterHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                text += input.text;
                input.text = null;
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout />
    </s:layout>

    <s:TextInput id="input"
                 enter="input_enterHandler(event)" />

    <s:RichEditableText editable="false"
                        selectable="true"
                        textFlow="{TextConverter.importToFlow(text, TextConverter.TEXT_FIELD_HTML_FORMAT)}"
                        buttonMode="true"
                        width="100%"
                        height="100%" />

</s:Application>
```

Comment: also how can I set inline styles for the html?, because i've tried to set style="color: red" and it doesn't worked, is that possible?