# How to use markup tag <img> in TextFlow object in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, richeditabletext, textflow

In the .mxml file, we can easy create the RichEditableText (RET) component with content of image in it:

```
<s:RichEditableText id="ret" height="600" width="900" selectable="false" editable="false" click="onClick(event)">
    <s:content>
        <s:div>
            <s:p>
                <s:span>
                    This is a
                </s:span>
                <s:img source="@Embed('image.png')" />
                <s:span>
                    span test!
                </s:span>
            </s:p>
        </s:div>            
    </s:content>
</s:RichEditableText>
```

But if I want to create content of RET dynamically, such as

```
richEditableText.textFlow = TextConverter.importToFlow(textFlowStr, TextConverter.TEXT_FIELD_HTML_FORMAT);
richEditableText.textFlow = TextFlowUtil.importFromString(textFlowStr);
richEditableText.textFlow = TextConverter.importToFlow(textFlowStr, TextConverter.TEXT_LAYOUT_FORMAT)
```

It always give the exception. My `textFlowStr` is like this:

```
<img src="image.png" />  **for html format**
<img source="image.png" /> **for Text Layout Format**
```

In this [How to add dynamically text and tags inside textFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16909916/how-to-add-dynamically-text-and-tags-inside-textflow), it gives a example, but I try `<img>` it does not work.

[This link](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS02f7d8d4857b1677-165a04e1126951a2d98-7ff6.html) says it support `<img>` tag. But I do not know how to use it?

Comment: This should work. For example: `richEditableText.textFlow = TextConverter.importToFlow('<img src="image.png">', TextConverter.TEXT_FIELD_HTML_FORMAT);` Pick one approach for the import, show us that code, and show us the exception you get when it happens.

Comment: Which exception do you get?